# Good or bad for a HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, css, html, validation

Is it legal to have 1 text box and 2 Label elements that "link" to that 1 textbox?

Let's just say that the Textbox is a search field. And the 2 Label elements represent 2 different types of things you can search for. And clicking on Label 1, for example, would focus the textbox and change the underlying form hidden attribute. For example:

```
<form method="" action="">
   <label for="search" id="books">Search Books</label>
   <label for="search" id="games">Search Games</label>
   <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
</form>

<script type="javascript">
   // IF LABEL 1 (BOOKS) IS CLICKED, THEN SET HIDDEN FORM ELEMENT TO "BOOKS"
   // IF LABEL 2 (GAMES) IS CLICKED, THEN SET HIDDEN FORM ELEMENT TO "GAMES".
</script>
```

What implications are there for SEO? I can think of a few but am not sure if they are valid concerns.

Comment: Nope, you'll be arrested for abusing HTML by the HTML police. jk it's fine.

Comment: I don't believe there are any negative SEO implications. Crawlers do not run checks on number of labels vs inputs as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Lol. I won't go to prison, will I? ;-(

Comment: @zzzzBov I kinda wish they actually existed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it, but it is poor design.

I would advise using a set of Radio Buttons or a `<select>` to let the user choose what they're searching for.

Comment: I would have used a Radio button, but I don't like the whole circle thing, it really screws with the rest of the interface (doesn't look so good). Actually, I think I'll check out Google's HTML source, since they have the same _effect_ on their page. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: It looks like they're using an Ordered List (ol). Why on earth didn't I think of this! I use lists for everything :-/ (exaggeration)

Comment: Thank you @Kolink, I have decided to go with an Unordered List.

Comment: Detecting an onchange event via radio or select, rather than an onclick event, is going to be better for keyboard users *and* mobile users (see: https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons?hl=de-DE).  The radio element shouldn't need to be visible for onchange to fire, as long as there are proper label elements in place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if it's 'legal' html/css ask the W3C validator:
http://validator.w3.org/check